# How can I toggle contenteditable H1 inside of ordered lists in Chrome?

Tags: cross-browser, contenteditable, execcommand, addrange

Create ordered list via `document.execCommand('insertOrderedList')`

Create h1 via `document.execCommand('formatBlock', null, 'h1')`

Toggle h1 via `document.execCommand('formatBlock', null, 'div')`

Expected: DOM replaces `<h1>` with `<div>`

Actual: chrome puts `<div>` inside of `<h1>` and when toggled, changes that `<div>` into an `<h1>` etc.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/devcon/pen/yLBYYJY)

Tried [deleting h1 manually](https://codepen.io/devcon/pen/aezgWN?editors=1111)